# All TFS questions funneled to Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion

I just went to ask a question on the [TFS data warehousing forum](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/home?forum=tfsreporting) and found them locked and archived (as of December 4th, 2017). It says that if you need advice, [to use Stack Overflow](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/27f162ac-e9c5-4cb9-a3e2-422e2585bdf2/the-discussion-for-tfs-has-moved?forum=tfsreporting).

But as I understood things, Stack Overflow was for programming questions.  Should they have directed things to Server Fault? (I have had poorer luck with TFS questions over there.)

Anyway, I still have my question and am considering posting it to Stack Overflow, but I feel it may be off topic.

I know that the folks at Stack Overflow cannot control what another site posts, but maybe someone should indicate to them questions on how to setup your data warehouse may not be on topic for Stack Overflow?

FYI: It seems that this redirect was placed on all Microsoft TFS Forums, not just the data warehousing one.

Comment: Well, not "all", Nichols does a good job steering bug reports, suggestions and support to their respective sites.  [tfs] has been an active tag at SO for quite a while already with 17K questions.

Comment: @HansPassant - I guess it is in how you think of a "question".  I don't usually think of Bugs and suggestions as questions.  As for support, unless I misunderstood, the support option is only those with Microsoft Support Subscriptions.  Either way, this discussion was just wondering if all TFS "advice" questions are on-topic for Stack Overflow or if someone should ask them to distinguish where they re-direct questions.

Comment: I did ask my question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47720351/file-missing-when-trying-to-do-a-full-build-of-tfs-cube  It felt off topic to me, but I added it anyway just to see.  (I have been very wrong about what is off topic before.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We have some general advice for supporting products with Stack Overflow (or other sites on the network) in [the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/product-support):

> We get a lot of requests from product teams about how they can use Stack Overflow to support their communities. Stack Overflow works really well for technical support and we welcome this, *within limits*. If you follow a few simple guidelines then you, your users, and Stack Overflow can all benefit.

The [announcement](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/27f162ac-e9c5-4cb9-a3e2-422e2585bdf2/the-discussion-for-tfs-has-moved?forum=tfsreporting) is a bit on the terse side, but it does seem to cover the main thing that tends to trip up folks: it provides other options for people to use when Stack Overflow isn't the right place to ask.

I see plenty of current questions on [tfs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tfs), so it *might* be the right place for some people. Server Fault [not so much](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/team-foundation-server). The other key is whether a representative from the project is monitoring (and ideally, participating in) the tag. I *do* see several users with "MSFT" in their display names among the [top answerers in the tag](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/tfs/topusers). Redirecting questions to Server Fault might make it harder for these folks to support the questions.

As a rule, I'm not too concerned with what other sites say about asking on Stack Overflow as I am about actual problems on the site. For instance, one time we had an [an Uber customer asking about their driver](https://jericson.github.io/2015/03/23/customer-support-2.html) because an Uber developer site wasn't clear. If that sort of problem is happening with Team Foundation Server, it'd be worth contacting them about it.